# while integration zXing1.6 to my Project getting error- This target might include its own product

Tags: iphone

i have followed same instruction.

1. Locate the "ZXingWidget.xcodeproj" file under "`zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/`". Drag ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and
    drop it onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files"  sidebar.  A dialog will
    appear -- make sure "Copy items" is unchecked and "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project"
    before clicking "Add".

   1. Now you need to link the ZXingWidget static library to your project.  Click the "ZXingWidget.xcodeproj" 
      item that has just been added to the sidebar.  Under the "Details" table, you will see a single
      item: ZXingWidget.a.  Check the checkbox on the far right of ZXingWidget.a.
   2. Now you need to add ZXingWidget as a dependency of your project, so Xcode compiles it whenever
      you compile your project.  Expand the "Targets" section of the sidebar and double-click your
      application's target.  Under the "General" tab you will see a "Direct Dependencies" section. 
      Click the "+" button, select "ZXingWidget", and click "Add Target"
   3. Finally, you need to tell your project where to find the ZXingWidget headers.  Open your
      "Project Settings" and go to the "Build" tab. Look for "Header Search Paths" and double-click
      it.  Add the relative path from your project's directory to the
      "zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes" directory. Make sure you click the checkbox "recursive path" !
   4. You're almost ready to go ..
   5. `#import <ZXingWidgetController.h>` from a file
   6. `#import <QRCodeReader.h>` for example because you will need to inject a barcode reader into ZXingWidgetController.

Any Suggestion??